# Timezone comparison in UTC returning true when expecting false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do a time zone comparison

```
time_finished = "2020-10-15 18:30:00 -0700"
time_finished.to_datetime > Time.zone.now.utc
```

both time_finished is already in UTC which I am trying to compare to current time

```
2020-10-27T00:00:00-07:00 > 2020-10-27 02:57:01 UTC
```

I get true when I'm expecting a false. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: _"time_finished is already in UTC"_ – in your example it's in -0700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time_finished` is not in `UTC` if you convert it to UTC then it is greater than current `UTC` time, which is why it is returning `true`

```
irb(main):001:0> time_finished = "2020-10-27T00:00:00-07:00"
=> "2020-10-27T00:00:00-07:00"
irb(main):002:0> time_finished.to_datetime
=> Tue, 27 Oct 2020 00:00:00 -0700
irb(main):003:0> time_finished.to_datetime.utc
=> 2020-10-27 07:00:00 UTC
```